# Mersenne Twister random generator - two VS2010 running in parrallel

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, random

Is it farfetched to assume that when two instances of VS2010 are running in parallel, seeds for random generator (Mersenne Twister) are taken from the same sequence ?

This would mean that seed for random generator is different whether I run the two programs one after another, or in parallel in two instances of VS.

Comment: You know that you can start the programs without VS, right? This isn't remotely related to the IDE / compiler, but how you seed. Tell us what you use as seed and we may help you. Oh: please make up your mind and tell us if you're using C++ or C, you certainly don't use both.

Comment: MSVC is a C++ compiler, it doesn't support C99 completely and is [unlikely to](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/06/c99-acknowledged-at-last-as-microsoft-lays-out-its-path-to-c14/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various random number generators don't seed themselves, you have to provide a seed.
If you don't, you most likely get `0`. The implementation of Mersenne Twister et al does not
share data between instances, so multiple concurrent processes will operate independently.

Comment: While it's true that they operate independently it's important to stress that they will independently generate the exact same sequence if the same seed is used.

Comment: The `<random>` engines do have default seeds and for `std::mersenne_twister_engine` the default is `5489u` not `0`.